# window.history.back() not being called - jest enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I wrote a simple unit test for the following. I am new to React JS testing - Trying to run a test using jest and enzyme.

```
     render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="not-found">
      <div className='_2'>WAS NOT FOUND</div>
            <div onClick={() => {window.history.back()}} className='not-found- 
 btn' href='/'>GO BACK</div>
```

)
       }
     }

The file looks simple, there are no props and the only thing not being covered when the test is running is onClick . How could I test onClick and make sure the test is 100 % covered. Thanks

```
 <div onClick={() => {window.history.back()}} className='not-found- 
 btn' href='/'>GO BACK</div>
```

file.test.js

```
  // jest mock functions (mocks this.props.func)
   const onClick =  jest.fn();
 // defining this.props
 const baseProps = {
  onClick,
}

describe(' Test', () => {
let wrapper;
let tree;

 beforeEach(() => wrapper = shallow(<Component{...baseProps } />));
// before each test, shallow mount the Component

it('should render correctly', () => {  
tree = renderer.create(<NotFound {...baseProps} />)
let treeJson = tree.toJSON()
expect(treeJson).toMatchSnapshot();
tree.unmount()
});

       it('calls onClick event ', () => {
  const mockOnClick = jest.fn();
 const wrapper = shallow(
    <NotFound onClick={mockOnClick} className='not-found-btn' />
  );
  const component = wrapper.shallow();
  component.find('GO BACK').simulate('click');
  expect(mockOnClick.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: onClick={() => {window.history.back()}} You are creating an anonymous function here which you will not be able to test. You will not be able to reach 100% coverage. You can test that  window.history.back() was called, but not the event function itself.

Comment: Thanks. i am new to unit testing. How could i test that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd avoid using `window` history and instead use `react-router-dom` for MPAs. In addition, instead of using an anonymous function, you can use a `PureComponent` class (it's similar to a `Component` class, but it doesn't update `state`) with a `method` class function.

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/j3qo6ppxqy (this example uses `react-router-dom` and has a mix of `integration` and `unit` testing -- see the `tests` tab at the bottom of the page to run the tests and look for `__test__` folders to see the code)

**components/NotFound/notfound.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { Button } from "antd";

export default class NotFound extends PureComponent {
  handlePageBack = () => this.props.history.push("/");

  render = () => (
    <div className="notfound">
      <h1>404 - Not Found!</h1>
      <Button type="default" onClick={this.handlePageBack}>
        Go Back
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**components/NotFound/__tests__/notfound.test.js** (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54433025/is-this-the-right-way-to-to-check-a-method-using-jest-enzyme-for-react-js/54434202#54434202), you can also test the class method, if desired)

```
import React from "react";
import { shallowComponent } from "../../../tests/utils";
import NotFound from "../notfound";

const mockGoBack = jest.fn();

const initialProps = {
  history: {
    goBack: mockGoBack
  }
};

/* 
 the shallowComponent function below is a custom function in "tests/utils/index.js" that 
 simplifies shallow mounting a component with props and state
 */
const wrapper = shallowComponent(<NotFound {...initialProps} />);

describe("Not Found", () => {
  it("renders without errors", () => {
    const notfoundComponent = wrapper.find("div.notfound");
    expect(notfoundComponent).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it("pushes back a page when Go Back button is clicked", () => {
    wrapper.find("Button").simulate("click");
    expect(mockGoBack).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Matt thanks again for your help. You answered a previous question already last week and was really helpful. I will look into it later. Also I posted this one as well which i don't know why im getting an error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54518329/expectreceived-toequalexpected-error

Comment: @userr2591 Please provide a codesandbox example with the code not working. You can fork my example above and use that as a template.

Comment: The codesandbox you've linked isn't set up for testing nor is it implemented. Please fork my sandbox above (it's already set up for testing). And make sure your code is fully implemented (even if it throws errors/warnings). The more complete your example, the quicker I can help you.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/k2qypovm95 all set. i used your files.. new to codesandbox as well

Comment: I tried to run your answer but it will affect a lot of files and make them fail.

Answer (score 1):

window.history.back is being called, but it has a delay time. I can make it work using a Promise:

```
const Component = ()=> (<div>
  <button onClick={()=> window.history.back()} className="btn btn-back">
    Back
  </button>
</div>)
```

Component.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
     
const delayAction = (fn, time = 1000) =>
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        fn();
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
        }, time);
      });

let container = null;

describe("App tests", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    //unmount Component...
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    //mount Component
  });

  it("should call history.back()", async (done) => {
    const btnBack = container.querySelector(".btn-back");
    await act(() =>
      delayAction(() => btnBack.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true })))
    );
    // asserts..
    
    done();
  });

});
```